# React Native, AzureDevops and Fastlane ipa build failing

Tags: react-native, azure-devops, react-native-ios, fastlane, fastlane-gym

I'm actually new to AzureDevOps and its been two days I can't seem to find a solution for building my app on AzureDevOps.

Here's what I've done so far:

p12 certificated uploaded and applied in pipeline following this guide [Install Apple Certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/install-apple-certificate?view=azure-devops)

provisioning certificate uploaded and applied in pipeline [Install Apple Provisioning Certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/install-apple-provisioning-profile?view=azure-devops)

Now when I try to build my iOS app using fastlane:

1. cd ios
2. bundle install
3. fastlane beta

   - setup_ci(force=true)
   - gym(scheme: 'app', workspace: './ios/workspace', verbose: true)

I'm looking for a way to use the p12 and provisioning profiles certificate from Azure DevOps to my gym build. After looking a lot, I found that setup_ci does that automatically for me.

Here is my Fastlane file

```
platform :ios do

    lane :beta do
        setup_ci(force=true)
        gym(
            scheme: 'AlfaCarpeting', workspace: './ios/AlfaCarpeting', verbose: true
        )
    end
end
```

And here's my Azure pipeline yml file:

```
# Node.js with React
# Build a Node.js project that uses React.
# Add steps that analyze code, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/javascript

trigger:
  - master

pool:
  vmImage: 'macOS-10.15'

variables:
    - group: React Native Variables

steps:
  - task: InstallAppleCertificate@2
    inputs:
      certSecureFile: Certificates.p12
      certPwd: $(P12Password)
      keychain: 'temp'
      deleteCert: true
    displayName: Install Apple Certificate

  - task: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1
    inputs:
      provisioningProfileLocation: 'secureFiles'
      provProfileSecureFile: 'alfaCarpetingBeta.mobileprovision'
    displayName: 'Install Apple Provisioning Profile'

  - task: NodeTool@0
    inputs:
      versionSpec: '10.x'
    displayName: 'Install Node.js'

  - script: |
      cd ios
      bundle install
      fastlane ios beta
    displayName: 'Build iOS'
```

The Logs from AzureDevops

```
[05:38:20]: $ set -o pipefail && xcodebuild -workspace ./AlfaCarpeting.xcworkspace -scheme AlfaCarpeting -destination 'generic/platform=iOS' -archivePath /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2020-03-21/AlfaCarpeting\ 2020-03-21\ 05.38.20.xcarchive archive | tee /Users/runner/Library/Logs/gym/AlfaCarpeting-AlfaCarpeting.log | xcpretty
[05:38:22]: ▸ ❌  error: /Users/runner/runners/2.165.2/work/1/s/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-AlfaCarpeting/Pods-AlfaCarpeting.release.xcconfig: unable to open file (in target "AlfaCarpeting" in project "AlfaCarpeting") (in target 'AlfaCarpeting' from project 'AlfaCarpeting')
[05:38:22]: ▸ ❌  error: /Users/runner/runners/2.165.2/work/1/s/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-AlfaCarpeting/Pods-AlfaCarpeting.release.xcconfig: unable to open file (in target "AlfaCarpeting" in project "AlfaCarpeting") (in target 'AlfaCarpeting' from project 'AlfaCarpeting')
[05:38:22]: ▸ ❌  error: /Users/runner/runners/2.165.2/work/1/s/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-AlfaCarpeting/Pods-AlfaCarpeting.release.xcconfig: unable to open file (in target "AlfaCarpeting" in project "AlfaCarpeting") (in target 'AlfaCarpeting' from project 'AlfaCarpeting')
[05:38:22]: ▸ ❌  error: No profiles for 'com.AlfaCarpeting' were found: Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'com.AlfaCarpeting'. Automatic signing is disabled and unable to generate a profile. To enable automatic signing, pass -allowProvisioningUpdates to xcodebuild. (in target 'AlfaCarpeting' from project 'AlfaCarpeting')
[05:38:22]: ▸ ** ARCHIVE FAILED **
```

Comment: Did you follow the error suggestion `To enable automatic signing, pass -allowProvisioningUpdates to xcodebuild. (in target 'AlfaCarpeting' from project 'AlfaCarpeting') to  pass additional arguments? 
`   https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/issues/2886#issuecomment-465613422

Comment: Did you get this to work?  Running into the same issue myself

Answer (score 0):

If you open the project in xcode and goto **Build Settings** -> **Signing** you'll want to adjust the "Code Signing Style" to **Manual**. Here's the settings I ended up with (note - I am using fastlane match for cert and profile management):

[image]